# How to enable VS Code local workspace settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As described in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37519

I want to have the .vscode folder checked into version control, but I still need some local settings that should not be checked into version control.

The issue I referenced proposed a way to do it, but I was not able to get it to work. Is this feature (single 'multi-root' workspace) even supported?

Comment: yes a "multi-root workspace" file with only one workspace. It allows settings separate of the folder settings in `.vscode`

Comment: I specifically tried overwriting the `files.exclude` setting but it didn't work. Haven't tried other settings though.

Comment: be aware that a new workspace/folder setting **replaces** the user setting. Include all globs from the user setting.